# Register accessory to android phone, but when communication is established I receive “No installed aps work with this USB accessory”

Tags: android, libusb, ubuntu-13.10, beagleboneblack, accessory

I'm trying to register a custom accessory to my android phone (4.4.2, Slimkat and Cyanogen). I use a BeagleBoneBlack in Revision A5B running an Ubuntu with kernel version 3.8.13 as USB host. My accesory is recognized by the android device as the phone says "connected as media device" and the udev rules are properly set in Ubuntu. Now I want to register the accessory via libusb-1.0 API. I followed this guide up to step 11: http://electronicdesign.com/embedded/develop-aoa-usb-accessories-android-based-systems.
In detail, I can

- open the host device on ubuntu and get a file handle
- claim the interface send device info (manufacturer, model, description, version, uri and serialNumber)
- send the request to switch to accessory mode
- reassign the device handle
- reclaim the device

Now the host device should be ready to communicate with the android device. But at this time on my phone the message

> "No installed aps work with this USB accessory. ..."

pops up.

My accessory-filter.xml from my android application looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <usb-accessory
        manufacturer="\\@4"
        model="\\@4"
        product-id="\\@4"
        vendor-id="\\@4"
        version="\\@4" />
</resources>
```

I could imagine that my accessory-filter is wrong, but as I remember from earlier projects with vendor specific accessories, I always used it this way and had no problems. Or is the error somewhere else? Thank you in advance for your support!

Comment: You might want to revise the wording a bit to make it absolutely clear that the beaglebone running ubuntu is the USB host, to avoid confusing anyone more familiar with the later android-as-host APIs.  In terms of your problem, do you have an Intent filter in your manifest?  Perhaps you should have your app try the option mentioned in the docs to enumerate already connected accessories, as that might at least give you an idea of what the phone thinks your accessory is.

Comment: I could solve the issues regarding my connection. It was stupidly a typo in my intent-filter. Thanks to Chris for the hint, otherwise I wouldn't have checked my Manifest file ;) again. The message "No installed aps work with this USB accessory. ..." still occures, but at least I can send data from the BeagleBone host to my android device now. If anybody knows how to get rid of this message, it would still help me...